# Utility type for typed array

Tags: typescript

There is an array with elements of entities

```
interface A {
  type: string
}

interface B {
  type: number
}

const a = {} as A
const b = {} as B

const array = [a, b]
```

The array is of type `(A | B)[]`
How to describe a utility type so that it returns a typed array `[A, B]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). This can be done by casting the type of `array` using `as const`:

```js
const array = [a, b] as const;
```

See proof-of-concept here on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=31&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLATwAcIAuZAZzClAHMsBfLLUSWRFAIUxzyNORABXALYAjaAyYIA9iErI4yALyZ6C8mgDcWGXLDJRy1euQdtO2fLhQocfEYDacADQGAuid2VNQA).